# Extract a string between quotes using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have "input.txt" and I want to search for a string and extract a string between quotes
my input.txt have only 2 lines :

```
name=' james carter'  nationality = ' usa '  age=32
name='fabio    rossi'  nationality = ' italia - milano '  age=19
```

I want the batch to extract the names (with spaces) from quotes and put them in variables (in this case only two variables is needed). For example I want to set two variables:

```
name= james carter
name=fabio    rossi
```

So I can use these variables in batch to do some future maniplation.

ps. its ok to use sed if necessary

**edit**

it seems to be impossible , so I wonder if can just take the string keeping quotes ,like this

```
name1=' james carter'
name2='fabio    rossi'
```

so the problem now is,to take what start after `name='` and end with `'`

Comment: What did you tried? Where did your code fails?

Comment: the problem that, if i remove the quotes from the input , then it will take only james discarding carter because of the spaces , even there is the problem of it begin with space , so I decided to put the name between single quotes (i didnt use "" because it seem make problem with batch file) but now i dont know how extract what between them , also tried with sed but the problem that sed process all the file not line by line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "INPUT_FILE=input.txt"
set "SED_CMD=sed "s/name='\(.[^^']*\)'.*/\1/""
set i=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`findstr "name=" %INPUT_FILE%`) do (
    set /a i+=1
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%v in (`echo %%a ^| %SED_CMD%`) do (
        echo %%v
    )
)
```

You will then have enumerated variables (`name1`, `name2`), etc. with the values you want.
Note that this works on any line with the specified form (*i.e.* `name='something' blah blah`).

**EDIT**: modified the code to discard lines that don't contain the string `name=`.

Comment: Can the same problem be solved using only grep ? is there an expression to find name='bal bla' and take out bla bla ?

Comment: @Leo92 yea, but you can also use dbenham's solution, which doesn't use Sed or grep at all.

Comment: yeah but this not my point , I Want to improve my grep skills , so please teach me how to do it using only grep

Answer (score 2):

If each line of interest is always formatted the same, starting with `name='`, then a native batch solution is simple:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set input="test.txt"
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=:'" %%A in (
  'findstr /b /c:"name='" %input% ^| findstr /n "^"'
) do set "name%%A=%%B"
```

This solution assumes that the name value never contains the `:` character.